# pygtk custom widgets displaying in separate window

Tags: python, gtk, widget, pygtk, pycairo

I'm having trouble with custom widgets showing up in a separate window. Separate window not in the sense of all widgets being in a window, but they all come up separately with their own window decorations. I'm not sure where the problem would be, but I guessed it might be in one of the following, maybe to do with how I'm creating the window. do_realize is called in **init** (which also appears below), and I think do_expose_event is called by gtk when it's asked to draw itself, but I'm not really sure (I'm very new to all this). I put a print statement in do_expose_event, and it is called for each after a print statement that I placed immediately before entering gtk main in the program that makes the widgets. All of the code is GPLed.

If any other code is needed it's available on request.

```
def do_realize(self):
    """Makes a window on which we draw"""

    #set a flag to say we are realised
    self.set_flags(self.flags() | gtk.REALIZED)

    #make a gdk window to draw on
    self.window = gtk.gdk.Window(self.get_parent_window(), width=self.allocation.width,
                    height=self.allocation.height, window_type=gtk.gdk.WINDOW_CHILD,
                    wclass=gtk.gdk.INPUT_OUTPUT, event_mask=self.get_events() | gtk.gdk.EXPOSURE_MASK)

    #associate the window with the widget
    self.window.set_user_data(self)

    #attach a style
    self.style.attach(self.window)

    #set the default background colour to whatever the theme says, and the state
    self.style.set_background(self.window, gtk.STATE_NORMAL)
    self.window.move_resize(*self.allocation)

def do_expose_event(self, event):
    """Called when the widget is asked to draw itself"""
    #put the allocation in some variables
    x, y, w, h = self.allocation
    cr = self.window.cairo_create()


    #if height is greater than width
    if (h > w):
        scale = h/float(BASE_SIZE)
    else:
        scale = w/float(BASE_SIZE)

    #set the scale
    cr.scale(scale,scale)

    #put in the colour
    self.draw_background_color(cr)

    #draw the highlight if necessary
    if self.is_focus():
        self.draw_highlight_box(cr)

    self.draw_normal_box(cr)
    self.draw_text(cr)
    if self.draw_boxes and self.is_focus():
        self.draw_note_area_highlight_box(cr)

def __init__(self, upper=9, text=''):
    """initialise it"""
    gtk.Widget.__init__(self)       #init the super class
    self.upper = upper
    self.font = self.style.font_desc
    self.font.set_size(pango.SCALE*13)
    self.note_font = self.font.copy()
    self.note_font.set_size(pango.SCALE*6)

    #set properties-can focus and grab all events
    self.set_property('can-focus',True)
    self.set_property('events',gtk.gdk.ALL_EVENTS_MASK)

    #connect the events to functions
    self.connect('button-press-event',self.button_press)        #box is clicked on
    self.connect('key-release-event',self.key_press)            #release of key when inputting
    self.connect('enter-notify-event',self.pointer_enter)       #pointer enters
    self.connect('leave-notify-event',self.pointer_leave)       #pointer leaves
    self.connect('focus-in-event',self.focus_in)                #goes into focus
    self.connect('focus-out-event',self.focus_out)              #goes out of focus
    self.connect('motion-notify-event',self.motion_notify)      #poniter is in the window

    #debugging info
    #print type(self)

    self.set_text(text)
    self.do_realize()
```

Comment: Where are those two methods called from ?

Comment: They are both called from __init__, I changed the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `do_realize` in `__init__`, I should be calling `queue_draw`. I got help on the pygtk irc.

Comment: I was also wondering why that do_realize was there ... but did not find the solution. Thanks for posting. I upvote both your entries for this helpful message.